# check same value between two Array android

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have two `Array` as below :

```
String a[]={"book","pen"};
String b[]={"pen","pencil","bottle","book","bag"};
```

I want to check, same value between `array b` and  `array a`, i have try with this :

```
for (int i=0; i < b.length; i++){

            for (int j=0; j < a.length(); j++){
                if(!(a.contains(b[i]))){
           //delete if not same
            }
```

so my question,how to check same value between two arraylist android?

Comment: you don't have to use 2 `for loops` for `contains`... since only 1 array is looping.. for `ArrayList` it is pretty much the same.. also `contains` function should do the trick

Comment: @Coderji because lenght between them is different

Comment: you are not moving `a` array( you are not using `a[j].contains..`).. you are checking the `b` value with whole `a` `a.length` time.. the contains function loop through `a` by default.

Comment: check @Hariharan arraylist contains.. he didn't do a for loop for b_array.. because the contains function loops it by default. hope you got the idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this..

```
for (int i=0; i < b.length; i++){

        for (int j=0; j < a.length(); j++){
            if(!(a[j].equals(b[i]))){
                //do something for not equals
            }else{
                //do something for equals
            }
        }
}
```

Or

```
ArrayList<String> A_arraylist = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(a));
ArrayList<String> B_arraylist = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(b));

for (int i=0; i < A_arraylist.size(); i++){
     if(B_arraylist.contains(A_arraylist.get(i))){
          //do something for equals              
     }else{
          //do something for not equals
          int index = B_arraylist.indexOf(A_arraylist.get(i));
          B_arraylist.remove(index);
     }
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
B_arraylist.retainAll(A_arraylist);
```

Comment: Why not just write `B_arrayList.retainAll(A_arraylist);` ?  Don't reinvent wheels!

Comment: @Hariharan now its not delete anything

Comment: @NenMa just use `B_arraylist.retainAll(A_arraylist);` see my edit.

Comment: where do i must to put `B_arraylist.retainAll(A_arraylist);`?

Comment: @NenMa did you get the result.

Comment: well I have try your method, and when I print it, I got true in my logcat, I still not understand how to delete different value in my case

Comment: @NenMa you need to delete all the value except "book","pen" in B_arraylist correct.

Comment: yeah, that's my question how to delete it? T.T

Comment: @NenMa after using retainAll did you print that B_arraylist arraylist.

Comment: @NenMa what happen? Is that Correctly displayed ot not?

Comment: @Hariharan yes, I have, so what am I To do?

Comment: @NenMa Is it dispaying  "book","pen" only or some others.\

Comment: yes, it is displaying only same value they are : "book" and "pen", so how can i delete other value except both of them?

Comment: @NenMa after deleting only it displaying "book","pen" that 2.

Comment: so you said, `retainAll` can be used for different value, and display only same value?

Comment: @NenMa yes it'll display same value. other values will delete.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way. Use `.equals()` method in [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) API

```
for (int i=0; i < b.length; i++){

    for (int j=0; j < a.length; j++){
         if(a[j].equals(b[i])){
             // a[j] matches b[i]. Perform operation when they are equal                            
         }else{
             // it doesn't match
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: how if i want to remove if b!=a ?

Comment: You can create a temp list where you can put only values which satisfy the condition. Instead of converting the arrays to list and create a resultant list after checking the conditions, you can create the resultant list from the arrays itself.

Answer (score 1):

try this . I used it for int array you can modified it for string

```
        int[] arr1 = {4,7,3,9,2};
        int[] arr2 = {3,2,12,9,40,32,4};
        for(int i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<arr2.length;j++){
                if(arr1[i]==arr2[j]){
                    System.out.println(arr1[i]);
                }
            }
        }
```

Or if your using ArrayList then try below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list_One = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> list_two = new ArrayList<String>();

        list_One.add("A");
        list_One.add("B");
        list_One.add("C");
        list_One.add("D");

        list_two.add("E");
        list_two.add("F");
        list_two.add("C");
        list_two.add("D");


        System.out.println("is list_two Containts List_one Elements ?");

        Iterator<String> itr =list_two.iterator();

        while(itr.hasNext()){
            String list_two_element = itr.next();

            if(list_One.contains(list_two_element)){
                System.out.println("Matching Element found in list two : " + list_two_element);
            }

        }
    }
```

Hope this will help you.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `Collections` now renames to `Guava`

Get the jar file from [here](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)

Since the length of the array list is different what you can do is:

1.Get the lengh of the array with the largest size

```
int sizeOfArrayOne = array.length;
int sizeOfArrayTwo = array2.length;
```

compare the sizes

2.Once you obtain which array is the largest you could then use Guava to find for you the values from another array like:

```
String value = Iterables.find(arrayWithLargerSize, new SearchForString(arrayOfSmallerSize[i]),null);
if(value == null) {
    // the string is not present in the array
}else {
    // the string is present in the array
}
```

Run this block inside a loop of the smaller array (the *i* represents the i for the loop).

3.Write the search predicate class like this:

```
class SearchForString implements Predicate<String> {
     // override the methods here
     // also ensure that you implement the correct predicate
     // one that belongs to the guava collection
}
```

Hope this clue suffices!

Answer (score 1):

```
String a[]={"book","pen"};
String b[]={"pen","pencil","bottle","book","bag"};
for(int i=0;i<b.lenght;i++){
String firstValue=b[i];
for(int j=0;j<a.lenght;j++){
String secondValue=a[j];
if(firstValue.equalsIgnoreCase(secondValue)){
// item matches;
}
}
}
```